# Thread-safe Map: improve performance

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

```
public class EntityUtils
{
    private static final Map<String, Map<String, String>> searchMap = new HashMap<>();

    private static Map<String, String> getSearchablePathMap(String key)
    {
        synchronized(searchMap)
        {
            Map<String, String> pathMap = searchMap.get(key);
            if(pathMap != null) return pathMap;

            pathMap = new HashMap<>();
            pathMap.put(..., ...);
            ...
            // heavy map population operations
            ...

            pathMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(pathMap);

            searchMap.put(key, pathMap);
        }

        return pathMap;
    }
}
```

Map entries will never be removed.

Cannot use `ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent()` because of heavy population.

Can you suggest performance improvements to avoid synchronization when `key` already esists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some level of synchronization on get cannot be avoided, but concurrent reads can be allowed. Consider using a [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) to guard access to your search map. This is only appropriate if there are far more gets than puts.

```
public class EntityUtils
{
    private static final ReadWriteLock RW_LOCK = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private static final Map<String, Map<String, String>> searchMap = new HashMap<>();

    private static Map<String, String> getSearchablePathMap(String key)
    {
        RW_LOCK.readLock().lock();
        try
        {
            Map<String, String> pathMap = searchMap.get(key);
            if(pathMap != null) return pathMap;
        }
        finally
        {
            RW_LOCK.readLock().unlock();
        }

        RW_LOCK.writeLock().lock();
        try
        {
            //first check to see if a previous holder of write lock built map for us
            Map<String, String> pathMap = searchMap.get(key);
            if(pathMap != null) return pathMap;

            pathMap = new HashMap<>();
            pathMap.put(..., ...);
            ...
            // heavy map population operations
            ...

            pathMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(pathMap);

            searchMap.put(key, pathMap);
        }
        finally
        {
            RW_LOCK.writeLock().unlock();
        }

        return pathMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a classic answer that is completely valid. Looking for *potentially* faster alternatives, you can use the Java 8 `StampedLock`, which is harder to use but can allow for a better throughput than the ReadWriteLock (thanks to optimistic locking). Another possibility, if you are willing to consider the Guava library, is to use `LoadingCache`/`CacheBuilder`, which rely on finer grained synchronization just as `ConcurrentMap` does, and avoid the "preemptive computation" that `putIfAbsent`requires.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple collections to minimise impact but allowing concurrent writes.

If you use a ConcurrentHashMap, you don't even need to lock reads, just writes.

```
public class EntityUtils {
    // any power of 2
    static final int CONCURRENCY = 16;
    static final EntityUtils[] EU = new EntityUtils[CONCURRENCY];
    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < CONCURRENCY; i++)
            EU[i] = new EntityUtils();
    }

    final Map<String, Map<String, String>> searchMap 
                                             = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private static Map<String, String> getSearchablePathMap(String key) {
        int h = key.hashCode();
        int k = (h ^ (h >>> 16)) & (CONCURRENCY - 1);
        return EU[k].getSearchablePathMap0(key);
    }

    private Map<String, String> getSearchablePathMap0(String key) {
        Map<String, String> pathMap = searchMap.get(key);
        if(pathMap != null) return pathMap;

        synchronized(searchMap) {
            pathMap = searchMap.get(key);
            if(pathMap != null) return pathMap;

            pathMap = new HashMap<>();
            pathMap.put(..., ...);
            ...
            // heavy map population operations
            ...

            pathMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(pathMap);

            searchMap.put(key, pathMap);
            return pathMap;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Could a similar approach to taken to simply manage locks to synchronize the populating the of the inner map? This way only a single `ConcurrentHashMap` would be needed to manage all the known instances. If the first get call (with no locking) did not return any thing, a lock based on hash of key could be obtained from array and locked. Then behave similarly to the synchronized block you have on `searchMap`. This would add similar benefit of some concurrency of hash map population with less memory required.

Answer (score 0):

Establish a lock on the key.

Now you'll say that there may be two different String objects with the same value. True, but this can be avoided by requesting a unique instance of all String objects with the same value:

```
String uniqueKey = key.intern();
```

This avoids the lock on the entire Map, but guarantees that only one thread does the work to create a new map entry.

Of course, a lock on the map must remain, but only for the duration of the get and the put.

Comment: That cannot be used to access or modify the map. It could only be used to synchronize the creation of the internal map value.

Comment: The lock must be obtained for the get as well. Concurrent puts and gets can cause unpredictable behavior/failures for the gets.

Comment: @BrettOkken Yes, this occurred to me - just a little too late. Had to leave. - Still, I think that if the creation of the value takes a long time, a lock on a smaller unit is advantageous.